# jquery how to iterate through a list of attribute values

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I have this method:

```
$("#btnupdateofficeapprovers").click(function () {
        var checkedInvoiceLineIds = $(":checked").attr("data-invoicelineid");

        checkedInvoiceLineIds.each(function (index) {
            alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
        });
    });




<table>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Invoice.InvoiceLines) {
            <tr class="subheader">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="invoicelinecombobox" data-invoicelineid=@item.InvoiceLineId >
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </table>

<div id="updateapproversdiv">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => Model.Invoice.ApprovedForPaymentUserId, Model.OfficeApprovers, new { @class = "officeapproverddl" })
    <input type="button" id="btnupdateofficeapprovers" class="button invisibleforprint" value="Update" />
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is get all the invoicelineid and put them in a collection.

Next I'm wanting to run through each id in the list and show it in an alert.

The problem is this is throwing a big exception. Anyone know how to fix? How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the jQuery selector "Has attribute" : http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NF5Ss/1/

```
$("#btnupdateofficeapprovers").click(function () {
    var checkedInvoiceLineIds = $(":checked[data-invoicelineid]");

    console.log(checkedInvoiceLineIds);

    checkedInvoiceLineIds.each(function(index) {
       alert(index + ': ' + $(this).data('invoicelineid'));
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr()` returns a string. You can't iterate a string with `each()`. This is probably what you're trying to do:

```
$("#btnupdateofficeapprovers").click(function () {
    var ids = $("input:checked").attr("data-invoicelineid").split(' ');
    $.each(ids, function(i, v) {
        alert(i + ': ' + v);
    });
});
```

**Edit:** You can do like **@Armatus** suggested too:

```
$("#btnupdateofficeapprovers").click(function () {
    var $els = $("input:checked");
    $els.each(function(i){
        alert(i + ': ' + $(this).attr('data-invoicelineid'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.each iterates through a jquery object.  You assign checkedInvoiceLineIds with .attr() which is a string and does not have .each

Make it =$(':checked') and then in the .each access its .attr.